# How to click a focused button via keyboard on mac?

Tags: mac

For example, when I press "tab" to focus a button(to close something etc) and try to click it by press "return", however I can't.

Answer (score 2):

Press the <kbd>Space</kbd> bar. This should "click" the button that currently has focus.

I find the combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> act the same too, a "click".